# How store the result of a RETURNING * in MariaDB?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am trying to store the data I have deleted in a variable but it isn't quite working yet.
One of my last attempts was this:

```
newData:= (DELETE FROM ATableName WHERE AColumnName=100 RETURNING *);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to say, I don't think this has [been implemented yet (MDEV-8347)](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-8347).

A way to use a temporary table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE A100 LIKE ATableName;
INSERT INTO A100 SELECT * FROM ATableName WHERE AColumnName=100;
DELETE FROM ATableName INNER JOIN A100 USING (Apk);
```

This leaves `A100` with the contents deleted.